# how to search and replace through an entire block of text?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace every image tag in a block of text with a unique string. So far I've tried to get the index of the beginning and end of a tag, create a substring, and then replace the substring. The problem is that I cannot do this an infinite number of times (the text block itself can be long with an n number of image tags).

Here is my code so far:

```
var txtBlock = currBlock.getElementsByClassName("txtContent")[0];
var imgStartPoint = txtBlock.indexOf("<img ");
var imgEndPoint = txtBlock.indexOf(" />");
var imgstring = txtBlock.substring(imgStartPoint, imgEndPoint);
```

How can I repeat this process n number of times?

Comment: What do you mean by a block of text? `.getElementsByClassName("txtContent")[0]` is going to give you a DOM node, not text.

Comment: Well, maybe you'll answer this question. Are the images actual images on the page, or is it text that is viewed on the page as HTML instead of being rendered into elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this problem, and most programming problems in general, is to think about what you need to do and write out the steps that you need to perform in order to solve your problem in plain English.

To get you started, you should probably think about the following:

1. How many times does the code need to execute? How do you determine this?
2. How does the algorithm know that it is done?  Can you think of a couple ways to achieve this?

Once you have a decent logical plan, the code will be much easier to write.

In general, break the problem down to smaller tasks and you should be able to tackle almost any programming problem, regardless of language, etc.

Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you get your data from a DOM. So you can make yourself familiarly with the DOM operations and replace all image nodes with text nodes.

Helpful methodes:

- DOM Document getElementsByTagName Method - 
  http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp
- DOM Node replaceChild Method - 
  http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_replacechild.asp
- DOM Document createTextNode Method - 
  http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp